# Access an index of an array with dynamically generated name

Tags: java, javascript, arrays

I have some Java code which contains some arrays. Say one of them is `b`. I have a string `a` whose value points to the names of those arrays at different times. So if `a` currently contains `b`, I want to access the 3rd element of `b` through `a`. Something which I could have done in Javascript with `window[a][2]`. is it possible in Java?

Comment: Using dynamic variable names is usually extremely inappropriate. *Especially* in a compiled language like Java.

Comment: I am actually using GWT. I have some custom drop-down menus, with the same functionalities for each, like `dropdown`, 'click`, etc. If I can't do this, I will have to write a separate handler for each, when all the handlers are exactly same save the name of the element they are dealing with..

Comment: @Cupidvogel: Why don't your write the handler once, with a constructor that takes the array as a parameter and saves it in an instance variable and instantiate it many times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **collections**. Looks like you're looking for `HashMap`

Something like that:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

Comment: So you are suggesting that the keys will be the array names, while the values will be the arrays pointed to by them?

Comment: @Cupidvogel exactly. But instead of arrays you alson can use some collection. In the end your map will look like `HashMap<String, ArrayList<T>>` where T is the some type.

Comment: Yup, right. That was rather dumb of me to ask, since I already know Javascript internally uses hash to achieve this!

Comment: `Map<String, List<String>>`, why not a `MultiMap` (e.g. in Guava)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments above, I'll give you a pseudo code answer:

Write the handler like this:

```
public class MyHandler implements YourHandlerInterface {

    private String[] array;

    public MyHandler(String[] array) {
        this.array = array;
    }
    // your methods that have to access the array.
}
```

Then, when you can use them somehow like:

```
fileMenu.addHandler(new MyHandler(fileMenuArray));
editMenu.addHandler(new MyHandler(editMenuArray));
```

So you **don't use dynamically generated variable names** and still only have to implement it once.